# How to load .mat files in python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to load a .mat file, i used the package scipy.io and the output was saved in a dictionary, but i couldn't get access to the data! It was stored with a key "data" and it was saved in a variable x, where this variable is an numpy ndarray that contains two arrays and i want to separate them each one in a separate variables.

```
import scipy.io as sp
import numpy as np
mat_contents = sp.loadmat("data.mat")
print(mat_contents.keys())
x = mat_contents.get("data")
print(x)
```

The result of the code:

```
dict_keys(['__header__','__version__','__globals__','data'])
[[(array([[0.05, ....,0.02]
        [0.08, ....,0.06]
        ....
        [0.05, ....,0.02]
        [0.08, ....,0.06]]), array([[1],
        [1],
        ....
        [-1]], dtype= int16))]]
```

and i am expecting to put the first array in a variable data_points and the second one in a variable labels.

Comment: try `import tables ` and then `file = tables.openFile('test.mat')`

Comment: You have loaded that file correctly.  `x` is an object dtype array.  Looks like the shape is (1,2) (matlab prefers 2d arrays).  `x[0,0]` should be one array, `x[0,1]` the other.  On the MATLAB side this variable was a `cell` with 2 matrices.

Comment: @bla `from tables import open_file
file = open_file('data.mat')` an error has occurred  `unable to open/create file 'data.mat'`

Comment: `tables` only works on .mat written with the newer HDF5 format.  `loadmat` handles this file correctly.

Comment: @hpaulj I've already tried that solution but it was not possible because the size of `x` is 1 and its shape is `(1,1)`

Comment: Your print looks like (1,2).  In any case it's just a matter of indexing the array correctly.

Comment: `a=np.array_split(x, 2)
print(a)` i tried to split the array and look what was the result: `([[array[....] , array[...] , dtype=int16]]), dtype[('features,'0'),('labels,'0')], array([], shape=(0,1), dtype=int16]]), dtype[('features,'0'),('labels,'0')])` it's evident to find such a result 'cause in the .mat file the structure has two fields one is 'features' and the other one is 'labels'

Answer (score 1):

`mat_contents = sp.loadmat("data.mat")
data= mat_contents['data']
Y=data['labels'] [0][0]
X=data['features'] [0][0]` 
Data is a structure that has two attributes so if we want access to the first one's value we write this following instruction `Y=data[attribute]` Y is an array containing sometimes many arrays so we should specify which one we want to extract `Y=data[attribute] [0][0]`